# How to calculate the distance between two waypoints on an approach plate?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

[image]

Can you please show me how to calculate the distance between the 2 waypoints A and C as shown on the picture? I would really appreciate it. I am having difficulties to calculate the distance between 2 waypoints.

Comment: Is there any Aviation Forum out there, where I can get some help? Please advise!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks

Comment: Are you having issues with the math, or with reading the plate?

Answer (score 3):

Point A to B = 3.2 miles, point B to C = 3.0 miles.

Total is 3.2 + 3.0 = **6.2 miles**.

Click this [link](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/glossary-legends.pdf) to see a complete legend from Jeppesen Charts showing symbols, definitions, etc. The picture below pertains specifically to your question.

[image]
(Source: [Jeppesen](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/documents/aviation/business/ifr-paper-services/glossary-legends.pdf))